# Automatically track all changes to a folder on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, version-control

Is there any software that can keep track of all changes that are made to the files in a specific folder? I'd like to keep track of the complete revision history of a specific folder (so that if I accidentally delete a file or folder, I can quickly restore it.)

Comment: What OS are you talking about?

Comment: I think your question is too broad, and has too many factors to be considered to be helpful for other people. For instance, Apple has Time Machine, while Windows 7 and 8 have pretty good backup software also built in. If you can edit it to be more relevant to a particular situation, I think that'll stop it being closed.

Comment: @RandolphWest Which Windows backup software are you referring to, and how can you use it to automatically track changes to a folder?

Comment: There's also a program called dirMonitor - it looks like it might do what I want it to do. http://helpdeskgeek.com/free-tools-review/track-changes-to-files-and-folders-using-dirmonitor/#comments

Comment: Every time the Windows backup runs, it can be told to keep a certain amount of history that you can roll back to, as I understand it. I've never used it though. I'm an Acronis guy on Windows, and rsync on OS X.

Comment: If the purpose of this is to be able to restore a file that's accidentally deleted/overwritten, why not just use Windows 7's in-built [Previous Versions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-vista/Previous-versions-of-files-frequently-asked-questions)?

Comment: techie007, from their question it sounds like Previous Versions doesn't act fast enough to file changes. E.g. sometimes you notice that it hasn't yet versioned a file for a day or longer.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, there is a simple and very useful application for Windows called [AutoVer](http://beanland.net.au/autover/) that monitors everything within a folder, and saves backups of each file every time it's saved (also at regular intervals). You get a copy of the last state of your folder plus a history of each file changes.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably write up something yourself. .NET has a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class for that purpose. All you'd have to do is to make a backup after each event, I guess.

Comment: Does git or SVN track changes to folders (and record all changes that are made by the user)?

Comment: Also, I'm not very familiar with .NET - I'm mainly a node.js developer.

Comment: With version control software like Subversion or git you have to explicitly commit changes you made. You could probably automate that but It kinda defies the purpose.

Comment: How does it "defy the purpose"?

Comment: A VCS is supposed to store changes to a set of files in discrete steps, called revisions. Revisions have metadata that helps making sense of them, e.g. an author and a commit message. They are well-suited for things that *a human* splits into different revisions. What you want is actually at a granularity of individual file changes, e.g. every save action on a file should be versioned. This could mean plenty of revisions and you'd use it just as a data dump and that's not really what they are meant or built for, so don't expect them to do it well.

Comment: In that case, would it be possible to commit changes automatically (at regular intervals) for a specific folder, using git or svn?

Comment: Yes, you could just make that a scheduled task. E.g. a batch file that adds all files and commits.